# Counting and grouping at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Mail` model with the following schema:

```
t.string   "mail"
t.integer  "country"
t.boolean  "validated"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

And I want to find the top 5 countries in the database, so i go ahead and type

```
@top5 = Mail.find(:all,:group =>  'country',:conditions => [ "validated = ?" , "t" ], :limit => 5 )
```

This will tell me the groups(i need an order by i dont know how to write)

```
@top5 = Mail.count(:all,:group =>  'country',:conditions => [ "validated = ?" , "t" ], :limit => 5 )
```

This will tell me how many mails are in each group

Im wondering if i can group and count in just one go

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Mail.find(
    :all, 
    :select => 'count(*) count, country', 
    :group => 'country', 
    :conditions => ['validated = ?', 't' ], 
    :order => 'count DESC',
    :limit => 5)
```

This should give you records that have a country attribute and a count attribute.

Comment: true should be used instead of 't'

Comment: @airportyh Rails API says that ActiveRecord.find is deprecated (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class). Do you know the best way to do this on Rails 3?

Comment: @Daniel: I've thought that before but look closely: it says "moved or deprecated" and actually it has been moved to ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find. (I believe you are still supposed to call Mail.find to access this method in its new location.)

Answer (score 24):

Try:

`Mail.count(:group => 'country', :conditions => ['validated = ?', 't'])`

I'm not sure count accepts `:limit` though.

**EDIT:**

I think this is more readable:

`Mail.count(:group => :country, :conditions => {:validated => true})`

Comment: In order to use the limit option you have to do: Mail.limit(10).order("count_all desc").count(group: :country). Similar to what tee suggests. For specifying conditions I suggest using a scope on the model, or the where option.

Answer (score 22):

With Rails 3 you can simplify it further:

```
Mail.where(validated: true).count(group: :country)
```

You can order by fields in the group - in this case only :country would be valid:

```
Mail.where(validated: true)
    .order(:country)
    .count(group: :country)
```

You can also order by the count, using "count_all":

```
Mail.where(validated: true)
    .order("count_all desc")
    .count(group: :country)
```

You can also limit the number of groups returned. To do this you must call limit before calling count (because `#count` returns `ActiveSupport::OrderedHash`):

```
Mail.where(validated: true)
    .order("count_all desc")
    .limit(5)
    .count(group: :country)
```

*Updated syntax for Rails 4:*

```
Mail.where(validated: true)
    .group(:country)
    .count
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had to group data with **city name** and showing **count** of how many rows are there for each city with **specific condition**. So this is how I did:

```
CityData.where(:status => 1).group(:city_name).count
```

Output of this was:

```
{:Mumbai => 10, :Dublin => 7, :SF => 9}
```