# How to count group by rows in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, count

When I use `User.count(:all, :group => "name")`, I get multiple rows, but it's not what I want. What I want is the count of the rows. How can I get it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting and grouping at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499767/counting-and-grouping-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 31):

Currently (`18.03.2014` - Rails `4.0.3`) this is correct syntax:

```
Model.group("field_name").count
```

It returns hash with counts as values
e.g.

```
SurveyReport.find(30).reports.group("status").count

#=> {
  "pdf_generated" => 56
}
```

Answer (score 26):

1. `User.count` will give you the total number of users and translates to the following SQL: `SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM "users"`
2. `User.count(:all, :group => 'name')` will give you the list of unique names, along with their counts, and translates to this SQL: `SELECT count(*) AS count_all, name AS name FROM "users"  GROUP BY name`

I suspect you want option 1 above, but I'm not clear on what exactly you want/need.

Comment: thanks hgimenez, what i want is select count(*) as count_all) from (select name as name from users group by name)

Comment: In that case, what Sikachu's answer seems more appropriate - you want the number of unique names, and that'll do.

Answer (score 12):

Probably you want to count the distinct name of the user?

```
User.count(:name, :distinct => true)
```

would return 3 if you have user with name John, John, Jane, Joey (for example) in the database.

```
 ________
| name   |
|--------|
| John   |
| John   |
| Jane   |
| Joey   |
|________|
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using User.find(:all, :group => "name").count

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found an odd way that seems to work. To count the rows returned from the grouping counts.

### User Table Example

```
________
| name   |
|--------|
| Bob    |
| Bob    |
| Joe    |
| Susan  |
|________|
```

### Counts in the Groups

```rb
User.group(:name).count

# SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all
# FROM "users"
# GROUP BY "users"."name"

=> {
  "Bob" => 2,
  "Joe" => 1,
  "Susan" => 1
}
```

### Row Count from the Counts in the Groups

```rb
User.group(:name).count.count

=> 5
```

### Something Hacky

Here's something interesting I ran into, but it's quite hacky as it will add the count to every row, and doesn't play too well in active record land. I don't remember if I was able to get this into an Arel / ActiveRecord query.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS count, COUNT(*) AS count_all
FROM "users"
GROUP BY "users"."name"
```

```
[
  { count: 3, count_all: 2, name: "Bob" },
  { count: 3, count_all: 1, name: "Joe" },
  { count: 3, count_all: 1, name: "Susan" }
]
```