# rails 3 group by and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model:

```
activity_types: id, name

activities: id, id_activity_type, occurrences, date (other fields)
```

The activities table store how many times an activity occurs by day. But now I want to show to the user how many activities from each type occurred by month.

I got the following solution [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499767/counting-and-grouping-at-the-same-time) which seems ok:

```
Activity.all(:joins => :activity_types,
             :select => "activity_types.id, activity_types.name, SUM(activities.occurrences) as occurrences",
             :group => "activity_types.id, activity_types.name",
             :order => "activity_types.id")
```

but this seems a lot of code for the rails standards and [rails API says it's deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class).

I found the following solution which is a lot simple:

```
Activity.sum(:occurrences).group(:activity_type_id)
```

Which returns an hash with **activity_type_id** => occurrences.

What shall I do to get the following hash: **activity_type.name** => occurrences ?

Comment: `activity_types: id, name` here activity_type name is going to be uniq ? grouping & ordering on activity_types.id is just because you wanted ordered hash based on activity_types.id, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the original query worked, then just try rewriting it with Rails 3 syntax:

```
Activity.joins(:activity_types)
  .select("activity_types.id, activity_types.name, SUM(activities.occurrences) as occurrences")
  .group("activity_types.id, activity_types.name")
  .order("activity_types.id")
```

Comment: Well, if I don't find any cleaner solution (1 or 2 lines of code), I'll go with this. But it just don't feel like rails

Answer (score 4):

`Activity.joins(:activity_types).group('activity_types.name').sum(:occurrences)`

```
SELECT SUM(activities.occurrences) AS sum_occurrences, activity_types.name AS activity_types_name FROM activity_types INNER JOIN activity_types ON activity_types.id = activities.activity_types_id GROUP BY activity_types.name
```

in case you needed an ordered hash based on `activity_types.id` and assuming `activity_types_id` is not needed as a part of hash key.

```
Activity.joins(:activity_types).group('activity_types.name').order(:activity_types_id).sum(:occurrences)
```

incase [activity_type_id, activity_types.name] needed as a part of key

```
Activity.joins(:activity_types).group(:activity_types_id, 'activity_types.name').order(:activity_types_id).sum(:occurrences)
```

Comment: It says that the activity.id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. I was able to fix this by adding a select clause, but then your answer is similar to @maprihora answer

Comment: you mean to say activity_types_id and activity.id written in above comment is typo error?

Comment: when I execute this command: Activity.joins(:activity_types).group(:activity_types_id, 'activity_types.name') it generates the following query: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "activity_types" ON "activity_types"."id" = "activities"."activity_type_id" GROUP BY activity_type_id, activity_type.name ORDER BY activities.activity_type_id ASC but it cannot group by activity_type.name because it isn't in the select statement

Comment: why do u need explicit selection for activity_type.name. Can you put down result of query?

Comment: In SQL you cannot GROUP BY something that isn't on your SELECT.

Comment: above query works proper at my end without any error, is it throwing any error at ur end?