# Rails Count and Group to return count and values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, group-by

Using Ruby 1.9.3.

Assume this example, simple table "cars" in MySQL

```
id | Model
1  |  Ford
2  |  Ford
3  |  Mini
```

If I ran this query:

```
select count(*),model from cars group by model;
```

I would get

```
count(*) | model
2        |  Ford
1        |  Mini
```

Showing me that two entries in the database have the model of "Ford", and one entry has a model of "Mini".

I can't figure out how to get the results of that query in rails (other then using direct SQL to load up an array, etc).  Assuming a model called "Car" for table "cars", I've tried things like

```
Car.find(:all, :select => 'count(*),model', :group => 'model')"
```

but that just returns the models, not the matching count.

I am looking for a clean method to collect all of the count & model information from the "cars" table that does not require the full direct SQL being used, and then flattening the resulting array to make sense of it.  Something elegant. :)

(and if there IS an answer out there already for this question, please just show me where it is.  I've searched for a while and all of the questions asked don't seem to fit my bill)

Comment: Hilarious.  After finally posting the question, the "related" links showed me the exact answer:  Car.count(:group => :model).   Mods -- this is obviously a duplicate question now.  I leave it to you to decide to keep it or not.

Comment: I am getting the count by Car.count(:group => :model).How can I get the records other than count? I tried Car.all(group: :model)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help you:

```
Car.all.group(:model).count
```

And here has other answer that can be useful:
[rails 3 group by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068926/rails-3-group-by-and-sum)