# Showing multiple logs on one day as one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a bunch of log objects that have a date. In the view I am showing them through

```
<% @time_logs.each do |timelog| %>
```

If I wanted to make it so that when multiple ones only showed as one if that happened on the same date IE:

Before

```
Date: 10/11/11   Something: 1    Something else: 2
Date: 10/11/11   Something: 3    Something else: 4
```

After

```
Date: 10/11/11   Something: 4    Something else: 6
```

Would I do this in the model, controller, view? Do I have to make a new controller? And what is the best way of doing this without having to alter the data or save it in another database and pull from that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the ORM you are using, you'll need to use the `group_by` functionality.

**ActiveRecord:**

```
Logs.select("date(created_at), sum(something) as something, sum(something_else) as something_else").group("date(created_at)")
```

More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

**Mongoid 3.x.x:**

```
Logs.collection.group(
  :cond => {},
  :key => 'created_at',
  :initial => { something_count: 0, something_else_count: 0 },
  :reduce => "function(x, y) {
    y.something_count      += x.something_count;
    y.something_else_count += x.something_else_count;
  }"
)
```

More information [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/).

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good to know some more details about your app like which controller is rendering this view, are time_logs collection of model objects, etc. However, I'll make some simplifying assumptions and try to answer your questions.

*Would I do this in the model, controller, view?*

This kind of aggregation logic best resides in the model. I am guessing that you have a model called TimeLog in your app.

*Do I have to make a new controller?*

No, typically you'd make a new controller for a new resource. In this case, it is the same resource, namely TimeLog, that is being shown in a different way. This would warrant a new view and a corresponding new method in the existing controller. Again, I am assuming that you have a controller called time_logs that is rendering different views for time logs.

*And what is the best way of doing this without having to alter the data or save it in another database and pull from that?*

Use the Enumerable#reduce method. One possible implementation could be -

```
def aggregate(time_logs)
  hsh = {}
  time_logs.reduce do |hsh, log|
    if hsh[log.date]
      hsh[log.date].something += log.something
    else
      hsh[log.date] = log
    end
  end
end
```

However, note that this is a O(n). As long as you are not pulling a lot of logs from the db this is fine to do. Otherwise, it would be good to pre-process this data and keep aggregated logs in the db and pull them when needed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `group` for this with `date` field

[This link may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068926/rails-3-group-by-and-sum)