# GROUP and then SUM within groups in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table with rides and one column value and one `driver_id`.

Now I am selecting all rides and group them by `driver_id`:

```
@rides = Ride.all.group_by(&:driver_id)
```

This gives me for example:

```
{ "5":[  
   {  
      "id":null,
      "driver_id":5,
      "value":936.0
   },
   {  
      "id":null,
      "driver_id":5,
      "value":39.0
   },
   {  
      "id":null,
      "driver_id":5,
      "value":63.0
   },
   {  
      "id":null,
      "driver_id":5,
      "value":126.0
   }    
] }
```

So 5 (in this case we have only one group) is the driver id and then inside we have all rides. Now what I want is to sum the values within each group. So what I want is something like:

```
{ "5":[  
  { sum_value: XXXX }
]}
```

The object probably will look diferente but the question is: how to build the sum within the groups?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails 3 group by and sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068926/rails-3-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: did you at least try to google it?

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: it's very weird because google shows at least 3 links on StackOverflow and many other.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done at the DB level and grealty improve the performances.

Anyway, here is the Ruby-Rails version of what you are looking for:

```
@rides = Ride.all.group_by(&:driver_id)
@rides.each do |driver_id, rides|
  @rides[driver_id] = rides.inject(0) { |s, e| s+= e.value }
end
```

This will fail if any of the Ride record has a value that is not a Float/Integer (ex: nil)

Comment: What would you suggest on the DB level?

Comment: @Ilya I approve your first point, but I don't understand the second one. Are you suggesting doing `rides.inject(:+)`? this won't work because Ride does not implement the `+` method (and should probably not). What am I missing?

Comment: @almo you can take a look at the post linked by Ilya in a comment on your question