# how to create a scope to select the records that are used by the most users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, scope

I want to select the Resources that are used by the most users.

The Models:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :kits
  has_many :kits

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources, :through => :kits
  has_many :kits, :dependent => :destroy

class Kit < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :user
```

I want to create a scope that selects those resources whose resource.users.count > 3

How can I do this in Rails?

Thanks

I am getting close but still have some issues:

```
scope :most, group('resources.id, resources.title, resources.url, resources.description, resources.author, resources.price, resources.created_at, resources.updated_at').joins(:users).having("count(user_id) > ?",5)
```

I have had to include all the fields for a resource because Postgresql is giving an error as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "resources.category_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

There must be a way to include all the fields without having to type out each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  def popular_resources
    joins(:users).where("users.count > '3'")
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, albeit a little inefficient:

In class Resource, make a class method which iterates through each resource, and appends to an array each resource that has more than "num" number of users.

```
def self.more_than_x_users(num)
  resource_list = []
  Resource.all.each |res|
    if res.users.count > num
      resource_list << res
    end
  end
  return resource_list
end
```

Another way would be to use the `find` method with a :select and a :group as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499767/counting-and-grouping-at-the-same-time) but then you'll still need to convert the returned foreign keys into an object. I'd keep it simple and go for the above solution.

**EDIT**:
After trying a few things out, I think this might help you:
In your `Kit` class add a scope as follows:

```
scope :most_used, group(:resource_id).having("count(user_id) > 3")
```

In case this doesn't work because my fields are wrong, think of how you would do it in an SQL statement, and try replicate what I gave you, by chaining the commands similar to mine. If you're still stuck, paste your SQL statement and I'll convert it into a scope for you.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Thanks Theo, is there a way to do this in a scope?

Comment: @chell Take a look at my edit in the answer above. Paste your SQL if you still need help and I'll convert it for you.

Comment: Hi Theo I will give it a shot and get back to you thanks a million